# Appium could not find 'adb.exe'

Tags: java, android, windows, sdk, appium

Im trying to run some code that using appium but encountered this error

```
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error:  
Could not find 'adb.exe' in
 ["D:\\MobileTestTools\\sdkGood;\\platform-tools\\adb.exe ..."
```

Why does this happen with improperly filled environment variables?

```
[C:\Users\XXX>adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.2-5738569
Installed as D:\MobileTestTools\sdkGood\platform-tools\adb.exe]
```

[image]

Also i have ANDROID_HOME variable with "D:\MobileTestTools\sdkGood" value

Comment: Did you restart the process which is looking for the adb.exe after setting the environment variable?

Comment: @AndiCover Yes, i restart and process and windows

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the error. Perhaps this error appears only on Windows 10.
Appium uses the ANDROID_HOME variable to search for files. And despite the fact that it was set without a semicolon, Windows added a semicolon to it and Appium will use it by default
[image]

[image]